# How to tag agile and agile tools?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope

I follow the [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile) across the network and I've noticed a trend to overload the [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile) tag with two meanings:

- Agile practices (manifesto, XP, kanban...)
- Agile tools (TFS, Rally...)

I know that generally speaking both kinds could be off topic, however in some cases they could also work -- e.g. programming questions about integrating with Rally.

I propose that we use the [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile) to indicate questions about methodology (which is how they are tagged across the network, e.g. on pm.se or programmers.se) and [agile-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile-tools) to indicate questions about agile-related tools.

Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: For SO, both tags seem to be off topic and I suggest `agile` should be removed (`agile-tools` doesn't yet exist). Questions about agile methodology are out of scope here. Asking about "agile tools" on SO doesn't make much sense - if OP has a problem with a tool he uses for development, why should answerers care if he uses scrum or not? People answering should have expertise in the specific tool, and IMO there can't be experts in `agile-tools` in a SO context (as opposed to a more abstract pm- or programmers.SE context), as it would mean they can solve practical problems with any such tool.

Comment: @l4mpi please use an answer if you want to propose something, so people can vote.

Comment: I don't think an answer here would be suitable which is why I posted this as a comment - for a burnination of `agile`, a separate question would be best; and the answer by Ian already states my point about the `agile-tools` tag. I rather think you've posted this on the wrong meta as any actual StackOverflow questions for these tags should IMO either not be asked on SO at all, or should not require a special tag indicating the use of agile methods/tools.

Comment: @l4mpi I don't understand. I posted here because the questions are on SO, there's no problem with tagging elsewhere. Also, the tags are not off topic, maybe the questions are, but not the tags -- it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Well I don't understand either - how is `agile` in a programming context not a meta-tag for SO? What kind of `agile` questions would be on-topic here that need the tag and should not be asked on pm/programmers instead? Consulting the "on-topic" list in the help center, it seems any questions would have to be about tools or be "unique to software development" and probabaly very borderline. So IMO you're asking the wrong question - my answer to "how to tag agile" is that you don't as it's a meta-tag for SO; and that any such question should either be asked on pm/programmers or without the tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds perfectly reasonable, however I suspect that people will tag their post with [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile) without looking too closely at the difference between [agile-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile-tools) and [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile). In many cases, I suspect people will probably use both tags as part of their "5-a-question" allocation.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t see much point in having the [agile-tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile-tools) tag; most tools have their own tags for questions about **how** to use them.

The questions about **why** to use them when doing [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile) development fit the agile tag.

I can think if very few tools that are ONLY used by ‘true’ agile teams.   Also in my experience the way a tool is used by a team has little relationship to the “buzz words” the team uses to describe it’s self.