# How should we proceed with the [agile] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

I think the [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile) tag should be burninated but I can't necessarily justify it based on the process per the site's guidelines. That point seems moot though if you just navigate to the [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/agile/info) which says no questions concerning agile are fit.

I'm thinking the same goes for [scrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrum) too. The majority, if not all, of questions will be about team or project management or primarily opinion based. That's evident when you search the tag.

If burnination isn't a good choice can we at least add Project Managers to the list of possible migration destinations on the migration tool? I found a post recently that was tagged with [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile), which seemed  off-topic in general, and so when I checked the tag I thought the correct thing to do was migrate it. But it wasn't possible and so I did nothing. I wasn't really sure it was worth bugging a mod about it.

What can or should be done about the [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile) tag?

Comment: I agree that the tag should burn and argued the same [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258758/how-to-tag-agile-and-agile-tools#comment38089_258758). Sklivvz however seems to think the tag belongs on SO...

Comment: @l4mpi, you can't win them all I suppose. I also can only guess, partly because I don't have enough time to verify, that was before the tag itself said they're off topic. That seems like an open and shut case to me...

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues

Comment: I believe these tags (offtopic on SO, ontopic on SWEng) serve a strong positive purpose of making it clear a question needs migration to another site (typically SoftwareEng, or else Programming), and allow us to both hint the user that, and automate the migration if they don't. So the positive outweighs any negative.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Nuke it from orbit, just to be sure.

Questions like this are already on-topic at Software Engineering, and don't serve any purpose here but to cause subjective discussions.

A lot of those questions may need to be closed, and a few more may just need retagging.

If you're going to go through the effort of removing the tag (which implies the question is on-topic and salvageable), **please** clean up anything else wrong with the post.  Otherwise, if you're not sure what to do, just let it be.

Comment: By the way, if you filter scrum from TFS and JIRA questions with the following query -- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscrum%5D+closed%3Ano+-%5Btfs%5D+-%5Bjira%5D+-%5Bvsts%5D, there will be 90% off-topic questions about scrum and agile, there are more than 300 of them. Feel free to close vote this, I am planning to do this in next couple of days.

Answer (score 10):

I'm with Makoto. These tags are relevant at Software Engineering (and possibly at [SQA](http://sqa.stackexchange.com)), but they're not really on-topic here. SO is much more about the actual code/task/problem than it is about methodologies like scrum/agile/whatever.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of OLD question on these tags, and as old questions don’t get migrated, we need the tags or organize them.

There are also some new question, about “how to setup XXX to do scrum” for example, where XXX is a programming too, and therefore the question is on topic.

**Shame you can't have a message box that is shown whenever someone uses a tag on a new question, then we could point them at Programmer.SE.**