# Why is there a tag called [scrummaster] on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Someone just asked a question on implementing the gitflow workflow in a [scrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29) team with the tag [scrummaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrummaster). Does the tag even warrant being on Stack Overflow?

The tag has only 7 questions left (all of them are [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscrummaster%5D%20closed%3Ayes)) that are more or less related to *managing programmers* rather than solving issues with programs. Wouldn't removing the tag be a deterrent from people asking more question that are related?

From the tag wiki:

> Scrum is facilitated by a ScrumMaster, also written as Scrum Master, who is accountable for removing impediments to the ability of the team to deliver the sprint goal/deliverables. The ScrumMaster is not the team leader but acts as a buffer between the team and any distracting influences. The ScrumMaster ensures that the Scrum process is used as intended. The ScrumMaster is the enforcer of rules. A key part of the ScrumMaster’s role is to protect the team and keep them focused on the tasks at hand. The role has also been referred to as servant-leader to reinforce these dual perspectives.

Comment: No, this tag will be useful in identifying pertinent issues in the question if it is used correctly, and from a quick scan through it seems like most of these questions are using the tag correctly

Comment: I'd rather it were hyphenated, but `scrum-master` has nothing, so I think it's OK.

Comment: Well thse questions arent't:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454069/plan-several-sprints-at-once
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28137671/rating-for-user-stories-is-it-a-good-idea
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799115/scrum-estimate-product-backlog-items-in-ideal-days
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915536/should-the-scrum-master-do-things-like-bringing-us-coffee-etc-details-inside

Comment: In face there are very few that can actually be called a programming issue. All are more or less related to *managing programmers* rather than solving issues in programs

Comment: Yeah, looking closer it seems like a lot of them have nothing to do with programming. Make an edit and I'll vote up

Comment: It's used to identify what questions need to be closed and deleted

Comment: There's also [scrum](http://stackoverflow.com/?tags=scrum) which could do with a cleanup too.

Comment: This tag is a good honeypot.

Comment: `agile`|`scrum`: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289953/how-to-proceed-with-the-agile-tag

Comment: @DavidS: "Good honeypot", I've learned, is code for "should immediately be burninated and perhaps blacklisted". [tag:homework], after all, is an *excellent* honeypot.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: But blacklisting the tag won't stop people from posting homework, right? It'll just make it harder to find. I assume the homework tag is empty right now for exactly that reason.

Comment: @DavidS: It's empty because it was blacklisted long ago.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Oh. Well, still: it's not going to stop people from posting homework; it's just going to stop them from making it blatantly obvious. That's my theory.

Comment: i see nothing wrong in people posting homework when they do correct questions and need help after trying and looking for them selves for concrete problem. i learned more Java EE here than in the university
I see wrong when they ask do all for me.
After all could be a tag called my-boss-want-new-feature too

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a tag that is useful in pointing out what needs to be closed and deleted.

Going over the list of questions tagged with [scrummaster](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscrummaster%5D+closed%3A0) and even [scrum](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscrum%5D+closed%3A0) it's clearly a lot of questions that need to be done away with.

Eventually when they're all deleted the tag will disappear.

It was created in the first place because [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6214/should-scrum-methodology-questions-be-in-pm-or-programmers-stack-exchange) either did not exist at the time, or they already had Stack Overflow open.

Comment: Maybe you mean "moved to Programmers" (or similar) rather than "deleted"? If the questions have answers, and helped people in the past, they may still help people in the future, and people may have bookmarked them. Deleting would therefore be antisocial.

Comment: Deletion is the right action. Q&A on best keyboard tilt may also be helpful, but doesn't stop it from being out of scope, not belonging on the site in the first place

Comment: @sampablokuper there is also a time limit on migrating questions from site to site. Past a certain date, migration is no longer possible.

Comment: @RubberDuck, that's a pity. It would be nice if it were possible to move the question elsewhere within the SE network, but leave a note (or an HTTP redirect) at the original URL so that bookmarks & other links would not get broken.

Comment: @random (Keyboards are irrelevant; I won't engage in reasoning by analogy.) Deletion should be a last resort. If a question is out of scope on the site but in scope on another site in the network, it should be moved to that other site if possible, so that the effort the community put into it isn't lost. If *not* possible, then consider: **SO exists to help programmers**, not merely as an exercise in narrowly applying poorly-defined scope rules; so if any particular Q&A *helped people create software*, then let that Q&A remain in existence. To do otherwise would be pettifogging :)

Comment: Also, be wary of anachronism, i.e. applying today's standards to previous years' questions. SO used to be more inclusionist than it is now: questions were accepted if they were at least vaguely relevant to programming practice; and rightly so if they were helpful to at least *some* people engaged in that practice :)

Comment: scrum and agile were never on topic or in scope. Just because programmers and developers thought that they were the only ones in the world using those techniques doesn't mean they weren't just putting anything they could into the Ask Question page

Comment: @random, why eventually? why not on priority?

Comment: @random What's the purpose of your "on point" quote in the link to SE.SE?

Answer (score 1):

Burnination is completed.

All off-topic questions were closed and then deleted.