# Do we really need these Software Engineering related tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I came across this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666378/paired-to-be-focused-on-an-epic, and it was definitely off topic because it was not related to programming at all. However, what surprised me was that this question had 3 tags. Taking a closer look, here's what I found:

1. [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile), [agile-processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile-processes), and [agile-project-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile-project-management) (1.3k questions total)
   ###36% and 42%, and 49% closed
2. [scrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrum) (781 questions)
   ###73% closed
3. [scrumboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrumboard) (28 questions)
   ###35% closed
4. <s>[scrummaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrummaster)  (42 questions) Burninated</s>

Also, a host of other tags such as [sprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sprint) and [waterfall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/waterfall). A comprehensive list can be found over [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues). Note that this is a burnination request, not just a discussion.

We have over 20k tags on SO, and *all* these tags are in the top 1% of tags closed by %. These tags certainly seem to be associated with off-topic questions that would rather be suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/. Is there any real reason for keeping them?

It would seem people keep asking questions with these tags. Maybe we could think of implementing a custom tooltip to deter such questions (maybe by directing users to the right SE network).

---

As a footnote, if you want to look at the all the top tags by close %, you can run this [data explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/449112/percentage-of-closed-questions-by-tag).

Comment: well definitely *scrummaster* can be removed - 100% closed - wow

Comment: @YvetteColomb It seems like the result of a [burniation attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298534/2285236)

Comment: Yes... it certainly seems so. Curious as to why it wasn't a successful one.

Comment: I think for most of them replacing or removing the tag is not possible because the question needs to be deleted and deletion is harder.

Comment: While that might be true, there should be some way of discouraging the use of these tags... maybe a tooltip that can appear when these tags are selected saying "maybe your question would be better suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/"... or something like that.

Comment: LOL - I also posted a question in response to that question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355016/should-existing-questions-tagged-as-being-about-project-management-be-evaluated

Comment: @AndrewGrimm There's no question there - they are _definitely_ off topic. The larger question here is whether we should do away with these tags to discourage future questions of this kind.

Comment: Closely related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues

Comment: These tags don't have a lot to do with software to begin with. It is mostly project management fluff.

Comment: @VadimKotov This is a burnination request in essence.

Comment: To start, the wiki for each of these off-topic tags should begin with a cautionary statement as shown in the ['agile' tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/agile/info): "PROJECT MANAGEMENT QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Please ask these questions on ProjectManagement.SE - https://pm.stackexchange.com" (For some of these tags, a pointer to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com might be more appropriate.)

Comment: Close and delete, the tags will go by natural selection.

Comment: We can add the [project-management] tag as well.

Comment: There was also a recent request to blacklist several of those tags - I don't think it was done, though.

Comment: @Machavity I believe the two threads could be merged. Yours is a blacklist request, mine is a burnination request.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Possibly, but I addressed why we can't do a burnination in mine (see the quote from Brad Larson)

Comment: Sometimes the availability of such tags indirectly misinforms user that questions of such niche are on-topic for SO.

Comment: What's the state of this burnation request? It seems there is a high acceptance on cleaning up all those tags (and maybe more) since votes are at +75/-3 at the moment of writing this comment.

Comment: [tag:scrummaster] is gone now

Comment: @VadimKotov RIP and thanks for the update.

Answer (score 25):

Even that comprehensive list isn't complete: [development-process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/development-process), [sdlc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sdlc), [extreme-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/extreme-programming), [estimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/estimation), [time-estimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/time-estimation) (in some cases), [software-estimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-estimation)....

Most of these, if not all of them, should be pointed toward Software Engineering. However, you should be directing people at [our help/on-topic page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead of the home page to make it easier for people to find a definition of our site and pointers to other related sites. I would recommend this as a general good practice whenever linking to another site (assuming they have updated this page to provide a good summary of their site's scope).

I'd be more than happy to help out make sure that these tags are clean and appropriate, but I'm not super active on SO these days, so I'd like the SO community to take the lead.

---

I made some changes to the [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile) tag that I think should generally be applied:

I changed the usage guidance (excerpt) to:

> QUESTIONS ABOUT SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT METHODS AND PRACTICES OR PROJECT MANAGEMENT ARE OFF-TOPIC. Please consider Software Engineering or Project Management Stack Exchanges for these questions.

This includes terminology that aligns with one bullet point in the Software Engineering Help Center ("software development methods and practices") that is designed to encapsulate these topics. It also references the name of another Stack Exchange community (Project Management) where these questions may be on-topic. Unfortunately, you can't use Markdown in these segments.

I changed the tag info to:

```
Questions about project management are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Questions about software development methods and practices or software project management may be on-topic on the [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Questions about project management practices and theory may be on-topic on the [Project Management Stack Exchange](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
```

I removed the bulk of the useful content on purpose. I felt that it gives the wrong impression about the tag. If the only content is a warning not to use the tag, it becomes almost impossible for anyone to read the content to miss.

I did add links to the corresponding tag on Software Engineering and Project Management. In this case, both sites have an agile tag of their own. This should let people get a good idea of the questions being asked and answers being provided on the other communities. Some tags may not have a 1-1 mapping.

I would encourage people to use this wording on all of the tags that are better suited for SE or PM. If a tag is only suited for one site, please remove the recommendation for the other.

---

If anyone has any questions about the scope of Software Engineering, please reach out to me - I'm [one of the moderators there](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/4/thomas-owens?tab=profile). I'll be more than happy to help out with efforts to clean up SO tags and make sure people are being directed at the best place(s) to get answers to their questions.

SO mods - feel free to reach out to me in mod chat as well.

Comment: Yes, these tags have all kinds of questions that seem like they should be on Software Engineering SE or Project Management SE.

Comment: If there are any questions < 60 days old with these tags that you desperately want to adopt and re-home, please feel free to flag them and request migration. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray I'll do that as I can. I'll also try to create a definitive list (and put it in this answer) of tags that may clearly indicate a methods and practices or project management question. Fortunately, I don't think these tags are created all the time so it shouldn't be a growing list.

Comment: Please don't close the `lean` tag. `lean` is a dependently typed programming language from Microsoft Research, and most questions in this tag are on-topic, with good quality answers.

Comment: @AdamKurkiewicz It looks like lean has been cleaned up. It's been on my watch list since, at one point in time, it was used to refer to both the language and Lean Software Development. I don't see any Lean Software Development questions. I'm not sure if they were all deleted or retagged, but it does look good now. Thanks for pointing that out - I can remove it from my watch list.

Comment: Do you think that [tag:architecture] and [tag:enterprise] tags excerpts should also point users to [softwareengineering.se]? P.S. related [Get rid of enterprise architecture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421568/1595451)

Comment: @Rubén The [tag:architecture] tag, sure. Guidance should make sure to point to the [Meta Software Engineering question on design reviews](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/are-design-review-questions-on-topic), since a lot of that may be applicable to some architecture questions as well. However [tag:enterprise] is too vague - it could be anything from "enterprise" type software to enterprise architectures to something else. Sounds like a bad tag on SO that should be cleaned up. Only some aspects of enterprise architecture are on-topic on Software Engineering.

Comment: @ThomasOwens Thank you very much for the guidance.

Answer (score -10):

Yes, these are needed.

While the majority of these questions belong to the Software Engineering SE, many of them are on-topic also on the SO.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bagile%5d%20closed%3ano%20is%3aquestion%20score%3a1..) we can see the list of the

- open
- questions
- tagged with `[agile]`
- having a positive score
- in decreasing order of their voting score.

We can see 117 questions in this list, some of them might be closed as off-topic, but surely not all.

The rest deserves the existence of this tag.

Comment: Being open and upvoted does not mean they are on-topic. Almost all of the question on your list are either off-topic or do not require the agile tag. Isn't your whole argument for keeping those tags that there are question with that tag that are open and upvoted?

Comment: @BDL Then first they should be *all* closed, deleted and then also the tag will automatically disappear. However, even if *all of these questions* would be closed as off-topic, their deletion is impossible due to their high voting score. Thus, the tags will remain. Some of the question might also deserve a historical lock by the mods. If it happens, the tags become undeletable (as there is no more non-mod way to remove them from the questions). You see correctly my argument, I would also extend with a more broad view: some tags might be useful to show the direction to the SoftwareEng SE.