# Should existing questions tagged as being about project management be evaluated for whether they are off-topic?

Tags: discussion, tags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666378/paired-to-be-focused-on-an-epic) was tagged as being about [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile), [scrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrum) and [scrummaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrummaster), and when I voted to close with the rationale "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about project management, not about programming", the OP responded with "There are plenty if u do a search stackoverflow.com/search?q=scrum , which are not directly related to 'programming' per se?"

Looking at that search, I saw that some but not all of the questions on the first page of results were closed as off-topic. Examples of questions that haven't been closed are [Scrum and Fogbugz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315585/scrum-and-fogbugz) , [Scrum and requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549436/scrum-and-requirements) , [SCRUM + MS Project Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934558/scrum-ms-project-server) , and [Best ways to fit bug fixing into a Scrum process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593328/best-ways-to-fit-bug-fixing-into-a-scrum-process) .

However, it's worth noting that all three tags mention in all caps not to ask questions about these topics.

Should existing questions using these tags be evaluated to see if they are off-topic?

Related question from July: [Blacklist [agile], [scrum] and [project-management]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351809/blacklist-agile-scrum-and-project-management)

Comment: Their current state is what you should evaluate: are they, as currently written, within the full scope of the site (unique to software development plus one of the other three)? If not, just close them as they come.

Comment: TL;DR from duplicates: Yes, questions that do not meet our guidelines should be closed, regardless of their age. But it is probably not worth yours or anyone else's time to go hunting for them. Only vote to close if you come across them naturally (such as if they are causing a problem, like attracting new answers).