# Should questions off-topic on SO but on-topic elsewhere (like agile and scrum tags) be flagged for mod attention instead of closure?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, scope

There's been a lot of discussions about how to deal with tags like agile and scrum, and the solution seems to be the same so far - *close questions as offtopic*.

Recap on SE mission: "*Stack Exchange is a network of 173 communities that are created and run by experts and enthusiasts like you who are passionate about a specific topic*".

So, isn't "Blocking" people to ask (or not giving them an answer) against the basic purpose of Stack Exchange? It's *not wrong* to ask such questions. It's *wrong to ask them on Stack Overflow*... and we should *help* new joiners, guiding them to where they can have their questions answered.

With that in mind, shouldn't we **(EDITED) discuss about any solution for this** (like flag them for migration) instead of rushing for a closure vote?

**Related questions:**

- [Blacklist [agile], [scrum] and [project-management]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351809/blacklist-agile-scrum-and-project-management)
- [How should we proceed with the [agile] tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289953/how-should-we-proceed-with-the-agile-tag)
- [Is Stack Overflow an appropriate website to ask about Project Management issues?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues)
- [Do we really need these Software Engineering related tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355013/do-we-really-need-these-software-engineering-related-tags)

Comment: The feature you're talking about is called "migration" and its usage/history is fraught with problems.

Comment: The mods have enough to do already, IMO.

Comment: Why fraught with problems? It should be a straightforward process... could you please elaborate?

Comment: The amount of questions per day on such tags is relatively low and, *if the community* does the pre-assessment if it's a good candidate for migration, then the mod should take only 30 sec to migrate it.

Comment: The community consistently gets migration wrong though. You should look into the history of [codereview.se]...

Comment: Please read the central [FAQ on migrations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: @snakecharmerb from a reliable source I learned [the mod queue is empty](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/45378108#45378108) so they have plenty of time to cause havoc across the SE network with bad migrations ...

Comment: @rene and to think I was feeling guilty because my NAA flags were being handled by mods rather than the VLQ queue ...

Comment: This is clearly not a dup, not for the given question. The original question states is *OFF-TOPIC* for listed sites. The subject of my proposal states *ON TOPIC* for the listed sites.

Comment: Besides, I'd bet there's good material that could fit and have much better attention on other sites around SE rather than SO, not only the mentioned tags.

Comment: @TiagoCardoso "The subject of my proposal states ON TOPIC for the listed sites" - very confusing what you suggest then - if question fits 5 migration targets SO have what *other* actions you need? If post does not fit those 5 site how it could be "ON TOPIC for the listed sites"? Side note: the post is not really "proposal" (as it is not marked as "feature-request")

Comment: Hi @AlexeiLevenkov, thanks for the feedback - hope you help me on a better wording. As is, questions are being closed as offtopic in SO and *no further action being done*. I'm raising a discussion to do something *else* with them instead of forgetting them closed in SO, such as flag them for migration to *other* SE sites. Makes sense?

Comment: Besides @AlexeiLevenkov, clarifying on the "not a dup" point. The problem statement for the post referred as dup asks "what to do if I'm asking to migrate a question to another SE site and this question is still *OFF-TOPIC* there?". My discussion is not targetting these. My question is asking "why do we, as a community, are NOT asking to migrate a question to another SE site if this question is *ON-TOPIC* there and *instead, leaving them closed @ SO*?" Hope this rephrasing clarifies your question.

Comment: @TiagoCardoso as you know to re-open duplicate you need to [edit] post and explain why it is not duplicate. In particular addressing "the community on one site has really no idea what is on-topic and considered of sufficient quality on another site" from the [duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251652/flagging-migration-should-include-more-options) would go long way to clarify why we need more migration paths (and not just manually typed comments with suggestions).

Comment: @TiagoCardoso note that post in the current state looks like "lets chit-chat about providing site recommendations on the main site" - just suggesting to discuss something for hundredth time without any concrete proposal is really too broad even here on meta.

Answer (score 14):

Unless they're *really, really, **really*** good questions, closing them is the best decision.  We don't want to burden other sites in the network with our unwanted crap.

Additionally, even moderators cannot migrate questions that are over 60 days old. For those, our only choice is to close them.

Comment: There's a massive amount of really good questions on SO with hundreds of upvotes. And even these are closed. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469358/what-is-the-difference-between-scrum-and-agile-development https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412525/how-does-scrum-work-when-you-have-multiple-projects https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109141/how-do-you-manage-a-large-product-backlog. All of them have a similar question @ PM.SE.

Comment: Besides, is the "mod cost" the only rationale for this? It should take 30 sec for the mod if the *community* does the previous analysis to assess if it's a good question or not and then ask for migration.

Comment: Yes, *if* the community does the analysis to assess if it's a good question, @Tiago, but that doesn't often happen. 9 times out of 10, the person who flags for migration doesn't even have an account on the site where they're suggesting it be migrated to. So, a moderator has to go read the question, read the target site's Help Center, and try to decide whether it's on-topic and appropriate there. Unless the question is just obvious garbage, then we can skip a lot of those steps and just decline. But no, you're right, it's not really about moderator time. I modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Realistically speaking, it is rather rare that someone who hasn't even bothered to determine whether they're asking the question on the correct site is going to produce a high-quality question suitable for migration. It does happen occasionally, but I don't count on it.

Comment: @CodyGray, although I partially agree, I'd like to think that (at least) new joiners are not considering if the question is on the right site because they're not *aware of other sites* rather than not *willing to search for the proper sites*.